# Why is an included C-header not found when cross-compiling but well when not cc?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, iio

I'm trying to crossl-compile the IIO tools from the Linux kernel repository for a Raspberry Pi on a x64 Lubuntu machine, compiling the whole Raspbian kernel worked fine though.
First I tested it on the x64 machine:
`~/linux/tools$ make iio`

Which worked fine. Next step adding some cross-compiler arguments:
`~/linux/tools$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- iio`

Now he can't find the file  included in iio_event_monitor.c anymore.
What I'm missing here?

Comment: Nothing I can see from here, sadly. You either need to rewrite the question or get lucky and find someone who was in your exact situation in the past.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure with so little info. But one common problem is that you have not provided a sysroot for your cross compilation.

Comment: I don't believe there's no existing package for Raspbian of this library. Why to compile at all?

Comment: I didn't actually fix the cross-compiling issue, I just downloaded the source directly on the raspberry pi and compiled it there natively without problems.